# GUI button and entry widgets problems

Tags: function, user-interface, button, tkinter, widget

So I seemed to have solved some of the problems of my last post, but have created new ones in doing so.

I've created this GUI so far:

```
import random
import string
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('200x50+650+300')

var=tk.IntVar()


def generate(size=4, chars=string.octdigits):
    x=(''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(4)))
    print(x)
    var.set(x)


def code(func):
    x=var.get()
    entry.insert(0,str(func()))


entry=tk.Entry(width=5,textvariable=(var), justify='center')
entry.pack()


button=tk.Button(text='GENERATE', command=(code(generate)))
button.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

When run, the window will pop up and print the proper result(a 4 digit number that it randomly generates(a result of the print(x)), but in the Entry widget displays "None1234"

Where is the "None" coming from and how do I get rid of it? Also, how do I start the window with a blank Entry widget? -is that just a matter of changing the state? Also, can anyone drop a hint as to how I use the GUI button to generate a new random number to the Entry widget each time the button is pressed, clearing the current number and poping in a new one? For now, although assigned to execute a function, the button does seemingly nothing...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> None appears because your function generating the number has no return specified.

```
import random
import string
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('200x50+650+300')

def generate(size=4, chars=string.octdigits):
    x=''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
    print(x)
    return x


def code(func):
    entry.delete(0,'end')
    entry.insert(0,str(func()))


entry=tk.Entry(width=10,justify='center')
entry.pack()
button=tk.Button(text='GENERATE', command=lambda :code(generate))
button.pack()
```

window.mainloop()

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you SO MUCH!